# How do you indicate which executor(s) vstest.console.exe should use?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, vstest

How do I direct vstest.console.exe to use a specific executor (in my case I have a custom one that I wrote).  It shows up when I ask for the list of executors (highlighted text):

> c:\src\vstudio\PleskHostingIntegrationTests\bin>vstest.console.exe /ListExecutors /UseVsixExtensions:true
>   Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 12.0.30501.0
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> The following Test Execution Add-Ins are available:
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.GenericTestAdapter.GenericTestExecutor
>           Uri: executor://GenericTestAdapter/v1
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSAppContainerAdapter.MSAppContainerTestExecutor
>           Uri: executor://MSAppContainerTestAdapter/v1
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.MSAppContainerAdapter.MSPhoneTestExecutor
>           Uri: executor://MSWPTestAdapter/v1
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.OrderedTestAdapter.OrderedTestExecutor
>           Uri: executor://OrderedTestAdapter/v1
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.MSTestExecutor
>           Uri: executor://MSTestAdapter/v1
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.CppUnitTestExtension.TestExecutor
>           Uri: executor://CppWPUnitTestExecutor/v1
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.CppUnitTestFramework.CppUnitTestExtension.TestExecutor
>           Uri: executor://CppUnitTestExecutor/v1
>       **RetryRunner.RetryExecutor
>           Uri: executor://RetryExecutor**
>       Microsoft.NodejsTools.TestAdapter.TestExecutor
>           Uri: executor://NodejsTestExecutor/v1

But How do I tell vstest to use this one (versus the other ones)?

Comment: Hi. Were you able to find a solution? I'm curious to try to run tests with RetryRunner.RetryExecutor. Is the project available? Thank you.